# Parse xml which is in private folder(WEB-INf)

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

I want to parse xml. I used jQuery ajax for it. But the problem with it as someone suggest me in my other post is my xml is in WEB-INF which is by default private. So I can not parse it through ajax. Then please suggest me some other way to parse my xml which is in WEB-INf. I need to parse it in javascript tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a servlet that accesses to that XML and prints out its content. Then, you can invoke that servlet from your javascript file and process it.

If you have to reach that xml file, perhaps the WEB-INF folder is not the best place for that file.

Comment: I am not getting how to import servlet in jsp tag and then make its object in javascript.

Comment: i imported servlet in jsp using <%@ page import="" %>, and my script tag is with in html tag where i wanted to make object of servelet..but i am not able to do this why is so, please reply

Answer (score 0):

This is a dirty solution, but it works

```
<%@ page contentType="text/xml"%>
<%
    java.io.File f = new java.io.File(getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/web.xml")); //your XML file HERE
    char[] c = new char[(int)f.length()];
    java.io.FileReader fr = new java.io.FileReader(f);
    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while((i = fr.read()) != -1){
        c[count++] = (char)i;
    }

    out.print(c);
%>
```